# Reverting to nvm default version

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I use 'cd', I always got

```
Reverting to nvm default version
N/A: version "default -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install default" to install it before using it.
```

this message, I tried to use

```
nvm alias default node
```

but it still won't work

it said "! WARNING: Version 'node' does not exist."

what can I do for this situation?

Comment: I got this "Version 'default' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions."

Comment: and when i ran "nvm ls-remote", I got  " nvm ls-remote
            N/A"

Comment: Comment I had same problem. I had npm in a project, but not in all. I had to make the solution on _nvm current_ and _nvm alias default vXX.XX_ in the folder were npm worked.

Comment: if you are not using nvm. check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74763557/12001186

Answer (score 39):

Give this a try:

`nvm current`

And then whatever the current version is (for me it was 'system'):

`nvm alias default system`

That should (AFAIK) tell nvm to use the currently-installed version as the default.

Comment: No one bothered to write but this is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: This one saved my entire career.

Answer (score 6):

Do only few things below:

goto => node_module =>react-native =>scripts => find-node.sh

here comment all code of find-node.sh

Save and run your project.

you will find project working fine. Thanks..

Comment: It works for me, but I wasn't able to understand why. Can you explain please??