# Running default RN native project in iOS gives error

Tags: ios, react-native

Any idea what is going wrong? I have updated all the relevant components to their latest version.

I am creating a default react-native project and trying to run the iOS simulator

```
npx react-native init {project_name}
cd {project_name}
npx react-native run-ios
```

I receive the following error:

```
/bin/sh -c {user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project_name}-epegcqhmisnuaeenegumkazvqqys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-5F4C70EF7D90A5A5BDAEB404279F232A.sh
N/A: version "default -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install default" to install it before using it.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

The script (self-generated) in question is below:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o pipefail
set -e

RN_DIR=$(cd "${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/../.." && pwd)

GENERATED_SRCS_DIR="${DERIVED_FILE_DIR}/generated/source/codegen"
GENERATED_SCHEMA_FILE="$GENERATED_SRCS_DIR/schema.json"
TEMP_OUTPUT_DIR="$GENERATED_SRCS_DIR/out"

LIBRARY_NAME="FBReactNativeSpec"
OUTPUT_DIR="${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/../../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec"

CODEGEN_REPO_PATH="$RN_DIR/packages/react-native-codegen"
CODEGEN_NPM_PATH="$RN_DIR/../react-native-codegen"
CODEGEN_CLI_PATH=""

# Determine path to react-native-codegen
if [ -d "$CODEGEN_REPO_PATH" ]; then
  CODEGEN_CLI_PATH=$(cd "$CODEGEN_REPO_PATH" && pwd)
elif [ -d "$CODEGEN_NPM_PATH" ]; then
  CODEGEN_CLI_PATH=$(cd "$CODEGEN_NPM_PATH" && pwd)
else
  echo "error: Could not determine react-native-codegen location. Try running 'yarn install' or 'npm install' in your project root." >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi

find_node () {
  source "$RN_DIR/scripts/find-node.sh"

  NODE_BINARY="${NODE_BINARY:-$(command -v node || true)}"
  if [ -z "$NODE_BINARY" ]; then
    echo "error: Could not find node. Make sure it is in bash PATH or set the NODE_BINARY environment variable." >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
    exit 1
  fi
}

setup_dirs () {
  set +e
  rm -rf "$GENERATED_SRCS_DIR"
  set -e

  mkdir -p "$GENERATED_SRCS_DIR" "$TEMP_OUTPUT_DIR"

  # Clear output files
  > "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
}

describe () {
  printf "\n\n>>>>> %s\n\n\n" "$1" >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
}

buildCodegenCLI () {
  if [ ! -d "$CODEGEN_CLI_PATH/lib" ]; then
    describe "Building react-native-codegen package"
    bash "$CODEGEN_CLI_PATH/scripts/oss/build.sh"
  fi
}

generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript () {
  describe "Generating codegen schema from JavaScript"

  SRCS_PATTERN="Native*.js"
  SRCS_DIR="../../Libraries"
  if [ $SRCS_PATTERN ]; then
    JS_SRCS=$(find "${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}"/$SRCS_DIR -type f -name "$SRCS_PATTERN" -print0 | xargs -0)
    echo "["../../Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/NativeActionSheetManager.js", "../../Libraries/Alert/NativeAlertManager.js", "../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper.js", "../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedModule.js", "../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedTurboModule.js", "../../Libraries/AppState/NativeAppState.js", "../../Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js", "../../Libraries/Blob/NativeBlobModule.js", "../../Libraries/Blob/NativeFileReaderModule.js", "../../Libraries/BugReporting/NativeBugReporting.js", "../../Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/NativeAccessibilityInfo.js", "../../Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/NativeAccessibilityManager.js", "../../Libraries/Components/Clipboard/NativeClipboard.js", "../../Libraries/Components/DatePickerAndroid/NativeDatePickerAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Components/Keyboard/NativeKeyboardObserver.js", "../../Libraries/Components/Sound/NativeSoundManager.js", "../../Libraries/Components/StatusBar/NativeStatusBarManagerAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Components/StatusBar/NativeStatusBarManagerIOS.js", "../../Libraries/Components/ToastAndroid/NativeToastAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Core/NativeExceptionsManager.js", "../../Libraries/Core/SegmentFetcher/NativeSegmentFetcher.js", "../../Libraries/Core/Timers/NativeTiming.js", "../../Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js", "../../Libraries/EventEmitter/__mocks__/NativeEventEmitter.js", "../../Libraries/HeapCapture/NativeJSCHeapCapture.js", "../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageEditor.js", "../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageLoaderAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageLoaderIOS.js", "../../Libraries/Image/NativeImagePickerIOS.js", "../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageStoreAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Image/NativeImageStoreIOS.js", "../../Libraries/Interaction/NativeFrameRateLogger.js", "../../Libraries/Linking/NativeIntentAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Linking/NativeLinkingManager.js", "../../Libraries/Modal/NativeModalManager.js", "../../Libraries/NativeComponent/NativeComponentRegistry.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeAnimationsDebugModule.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevMenu.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevSettings.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDeviceEventManager.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDialogManagerAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeLogBox.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeRedBox.js", "../../Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeSourceCode.js", "../../Libraries/Network/NativeNetworkingAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Network/NativeNetworkingIOS.js", "../../Libraries/Performance/NativeJSCSamplingProfiler.js", "../../Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/NativePermissionsAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/NativePushNotificationManagerIOS.js", "../../Libraries/ReactNative/NativeHeadlessJsTaskSupport.js", "../../Libraries/ReactNative/NativeI18nManager.js", "../../Libraries/ReactNative/NativeUIManager.js", "../../Libraries/Settings/NativeSettingsManager.js", "../../Libraries/Share/NativeShareModule.js", "../../Libraries/Storage/NativeAsyncLocalStorage.js", "../../Libraries/Storage/NativeAsyncSQLiteDBStorage.js", "../../Libraries/TurboModule/samples/NativeSampleTurboModule.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeAppearance.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeDevLoadingView.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeDevSplitBundleLoader.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeDeviceInfo.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativeJSDevSupport.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativePlatformConstantsAndroid.js", "../../Libraries/Utilities/NativePlatformConstantsIOS.js", "../../Libraries/Vibration/NativeVibration.js", "../../Libraries/WebSocket/NativeWebSocketModule.js"]" >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
  else
    JS_SRCS="${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/$SRCS_DIR"
    echo "../../Libraries" >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
  fi

  "$NODE_BINARY" "$CODEGEN_CLI_PATH/lib/cli/combine/combine-js-to-schema-cli.js" "$GENERATED_SCHEMA_FILE" $JS_SRCS
}

generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema () {
  describe "Generating codegen artifacts from schema"
  pushd "$RN_DIR" >/dev/null || exit 1
    "$NODE_BINARY" "scripts/generate-specs-cli.js" ios "$GENERATED_SCHEMA_FILE" "$TEMP_OUTPUT_DIR" "$LIBRARY_NAME"
  popd >/dev/null || exit 1
}

moveOutputs () {
  mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

  # Copy all output to output_dir
  cp -R "$TEMP_OUTPUT_DIR/" "$OUTPUT_DIR" || exit 1
  echo "$LIBRARY_NAME output has been written to $OUTPUT_DIR:" >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
  ls -1 "$OUTPUT_DIR" >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
}

main () {
  setup_dirs
  find_node
  buildCodegenCLI
  generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript
  generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema
  moveOutputs
}

main "$@"
echo 'Done.' >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
```

Trying to run from Xcode yields in the same error.

Needless to say, I tried running

```
nvm install default
```

and received the following error:

```
Version 'default' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't answer on Stackoverflow often but I had the same issue and used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984666/reverting-to-nvm-default-version) to solve it.

It basically revolves around the command

```
nvm alias default system
```

or swapping `system` to whatever version of NodeJS you would like.

Comment: damn this was the issue not sure why, thanks for helping to fix

Comment: Every time I create a new project from scratch (not that often), I have to google for something like this xD Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when building the IOS app.

Open a terminal and type:

1. git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git ~/.nvm
2. source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
3. nvm alias default system

Answer (score 2):

Rather than modifying the system `node`, applying [the commit that removes the `find-node.sh` script](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/802b3f778b4d2ecd22882b371a84293421558b8a) with patch-package fixed this issue for a dev on our team who was stuck with this issue.

The contents of our patch is simply

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh
deleted file mode 100755
index 5d6d2c4..0000000
--- a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/find-node.sh
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,56 +0,0 @@
-#!/bin/bash
-# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
-#
-# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
-# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
-
-set -e
-
-# remove global prefix if it's already set
-# the running shell process will choose a node binary and a global package directory breaks version managers
-unset PREFIX
-
-# Support Homebrew on M1
-HOMEBREW_M1_BIN=/opt/homebrew/bin
-if [[ -d $HOMEBREW_M1_BIN && ! $PATH =~ $HOMEBREW_M1_BIN ]]; then
-  export PATH="$HOMEBREW_M1_BIN:$PATH"
-fi
-
-# Define NVM_DIR and source the nvm.sh setup script
-[ -z "$NVM_DIR" ] && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
-
-# Source nvm with '--no-use' and then `nvm use` to respect .nvmrc
-# See: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2053
-if [[ -s "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" ]]; then
-  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
-  . "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" --no-use
-  nvm use 2> /dev/null || nvm use default
-elif [[ -x "$(command -v brew)" && -s "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" ]]; then
-  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
-  . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" --no-use
-  nvm use 2> /dev/null || nvm use default
-fi
-
-# Set up the nodenv node version manager if present
-if [[ -x "$HOME/.nodenv/bin/nodenv" ]]; then
-  eval "$("$HOME/.nodenv/bin/nodenv" init -)"
-elif [[ -x "$(command -v brew)" && -x "$(brew --prefix nodenv)/bin/nodenv" ]]; then
-  eval "$("$(brew --prefix nodenv)/bin/nodenv" init -)"
-fi
-
-# Set up the ndenv of anyenv if preset
-if [[ ! -x node && -d ${HOME}/.anyenv/bin ]]; then
-  export PATH=${HOME}/.anyenv/bin:${PATH}
-  if [[ "$(anyenv envs | grep -c ndenv )" -eq 1 ]]; then
-    eval "$(anyenv init -)"
-  fi
-fi
-
-# Set up asdf-vm if present
-if [[ -f "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh" ]]; then
-  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
-  . "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
-elif [[ -x "$(command -v brew)" && -f "$(brew --prefix asdf)/asdf.sh" ]]; then
-  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
-  . "$(brew --prefix asdf)/asdf.sh"
-fi
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
index 3ef9a71..304a5dc 100755
--- a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
@@ -79,9 +79,7 @@ if [[ $DEV != true && ! -f "$ENTRY_FILE" ]]; then
   exit 2
 fi
 
-# Find path to Node
-# shellcheck source=/dev/null
-source "$REACT_NATIVE_DIR/scripts/find-node.sh"
+NODE_BINARY="$(command -v node)"
 
 # check and assign NODE_BINARY env
 # shellcheck source=/dev/null
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb
index 1b8a078..d65c9ca 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb
@@ -289,8 +289,6 @@ else
 fi
 
 find_node () {
-  source "$RN_DIR/scripts/find-node.sh"
-
   NODE_BINARY="${NODE_BINARY:-$(command -v node || true)}"
   if [ -z "$NODE_BINARY" ]; then
     echo "error: Could not find node. Make sure it is in bash PATH or set the NODE_BINARY environment variable." >> "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}" 2>&1
```